# API to make horizontal-cover-flow-like-image-switching

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am currently writing an app, and I want a 'view' to make images be swipeable through them.

[image]

This is the thing I want to do.

I don't know enough CoreAnimation now for doing this, is there an OpenSource API?

Or do I need to learn CA?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing on that image does not really look like a coverflow animation. However to answer you question disregarding the sample image; yes there are ways to achieve this without actually having to implement them yourself.

One famous and commonly used example would be [OpenFlow](http://apparentlogic.com/openflow/).

Answer (score 0):

Another good choice for this sort of thing is the open-source [iCarousel](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/icarousel) .